# Can not create new partition

Tags: partition, fdisk, gparted

I have a CentOS system that has 508 G free space.
I want to create a new partition from it.
It locates in extended partition.
[image]
I create new partition and format it as anything (ext4, fat32), after apply it can't finish the process and gives me this error:

```
An error occurred while applying the operations
See the details for more information.

IMPORTANT
If you want support, you need to provide the saved details!
See http://gparted.sourceforge.net/larry/tips/save_details.htm for more information.
```

and when I save the `save_details.htm` it contains this information:

```
GParted 0.6.0

Libparted 2.1

Create Logical Partition #1 (fat32, 508.23 GiB) on /dev/sda  00:00:01    ( ERROR )

calibrate New Partition #1  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sda-1
start: 184424448
end: 1250263039
size: 1065838592 (508.23 GiB)
create empty partition  00:00:01    ( ERROR )
libparted messages    ( INFO )

WARNING: the kernel failed to re-read the partition table on /dev/sda (Device or resource busy). As a result, it may not reflect all of your changes until after reboot.
WARNING: the kernel failed to re-read the partition table on /dev/sda (Device or resource busy). As a result, it may not reflect all of your changes until after reboot.
========================================
```

I used fdisk and created `/dev/sda6`, and I see partitions like this:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l 

Disk /dev/sda: 640.1 GB, 640135028736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 77825 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa62a8bc3

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1         262     2097152   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2             262        5361    40960000   83  Linux
/dev/sda3            5361       10460    40960000   83  Linux
/dev/sda4           10460       77826   541113344    5  Extended
/dev/sda5           10461       11480     8192000   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6           11480       77825   532917056+  83  Linux
Partition 6 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

but when I use `mkfs` to format it I see this error:

```
$ sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sda6
mke2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
Could not stat /dev/sda6 --- No such file or directory

The device apparently does not exist; did you specify it correctly?
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Any additional information needed?

Comment: `$sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda6`  gets this: 
`dumpe2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda6
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should inform kernel about the changes made to the disk. for that you need to run `partprobe`.

`# partprobe /dev/sda6`

Then you should run `mkfs.ext4` to assign the filesystem to the newly created partition.

`# mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda6`

In this way your partition is ready to `mount`

`# mount /dev/sda6 /mountpoint`

Answer (score 0):

You must run the command `partprobe -s` before doing any operation on `/dev/sda6`

If you don't have that command then simply reboot the machine

Comment: With `partprob -s` i get this error: `$ sudo partprobe -s
Warning: WARNING: the kernel failed to re-read the partition table on /dev/sda (Device or resource busy).  As a result, it may not reflect all of your changes until after reboot.` and with `partprobe -s /dev/sda6` nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

you need to move/recreate the linux swap partition and ensure that it begins/ends on a cylinder boundary

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion : you should try to use fdisk  /dev/sda to add new partition.Sometimes gparted got this kind of problem.